# Should all countries have strict wine laws, like France does?

Tags: wine, laws

You can tell that the French take their wine seriously because of their wine laws. It may only be called Pomerol if it is from a small set of vineyards, and harvested by virgins at full moon at the south side of the hill or something rather. Very serious. But the wines are very good, and the Appellation Controlée does provide a degree of customer protection and quality guarantee that seems to work.

I live in Australia myself and although one of the most expensive wines comes from this country (Grange), I'm often left with a vaguely unsettled head and stomach after drinking Ozzie wine (no I can't afford Grange). Never a problem with European wines, or Argentinean organic ones for that matter. And other than prohibiting contamination with proven poisonous chemicals, there seem to be very few laws in making wine in most countries, I believe the same goes for American wine. It's allowed to boil wood chips and mix the extract with the wine to create a woody flavour, for instance, forget about rising in casks.

So after this rather lengthy introduction, here is my question. How come that this vital issue escapes our attention? Why don't all of us demand strict wine laws? What should it be anything else than crushed grapes that have fermented with the little yeasty boys that live on the grape skins?

Comment: I'm considering closing this as primarily opinion based as it stands.   Additionally, it appears to be based on a flawed understanding of French law.  AOC wine accounts for less than half of the wine production in France.  France does allow many of the techniques you describe (such as using oak chips instead of barrels, and acids) for non-AOC, or the majority of its wine.

Comment: So that means there is a choice then.

Comment: The choice is you follow the laws and you can put the Appellation of the village or area you grow your grapes in, many times bringing a higher price. Don't follow the laws and you get to put Vin De France on your label which is usually a sign of plonk wine.

Comment: Excellent system, I wish we had it here. But no-one here seems to be aware that such a scheme even exists. Or in the US for that matter.

Comment: I think Australians and American winemakers don't like being told when and what to pick. What to grow and how to they can make their wine. Sorry, it's never going to change here in the USA.

Comment: @SteveS. Vin de France is a minority of non-AOC wine.  IGP, an intermediate level of certification is the majority.

Comment: Whatever... I guess it would be declassified at a  lower level like Vin de Bourgogne or Vin de Bordeaux still not bringing the $$$ at that level.